# OSX Big Sur SSH Public Key Location

Tags: macos, ssh, public-key

On a new Mac-mini OSX Big Sur 11.0.1 I cannot find my public SSH key.

It's not in ~/.ssh as that only has known_hosts

Running the command

```
   find / -name "*.pub" -print
```

does not find any matches.

I have ssh'd into my server several times from this machine, it asks for a password, and I get in. I assume in doing this that OSX has somewhere created and used a keypair. Since this should exist, I do NOT want to generate a new key.

I'm wanting to add my Mac-mini to my authorized_keys on my server, so I do not have to type the password for each connection. I did this with my old iMac with no issue (.pub in .ssh as expected on that machine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that ssh will generate and use a keypair is wrong.

Upon failing to find a key, ssh drops back to "keyboard-interactive" authentication method, so the connection will succeed without a public key.

Comment: I was going to post this as my answer when I saw the question in my feed, but you already figured it out.  You should accept your own answer so the question gets closed.

Answer (score 2):

Your computer is probably using a key already added to the [ssh agent](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/agent).

You can list the keys stored in the agent and their location in the filesytem by running `ssh-add -l`. You can also see the content of the public keys themselves with `ssh-add -L`.

**EDIT: Sorry to hear it wasn't from the agent.**

There's only a few places your system could be getting the key from. Per the [ssh_config man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config), these places are.

- The SSH agent
- The default locations (in your ~/.ssh directory)
- Files specified in your SSH client config (/etc/ssh/config and ~/.ssh/config)
- Files specified in the command line

If none of these provide any clues, try running ssh with `-vvvv`, because it will show you basically everything ssh is doing.

Comment: I get "The agent has no identities." from both of these.

Comment: @J.McNerney updated with response

Comment: the -vvvv option is fantastic!!

Comment: Oh, yeah, it's great on many, many tools. It's usually available for anything made by GNU, and some other stuff. Specifically, it changes the *verbosity level*, and you can adjust the level with the number of v's. So like `-v` increases verbosity by one level. Then `-vv`, `-vvv`, and `-vvvv` each have more detail than the previous. I think the max number of v's varies by tool.